# Connecting Salesforce with asp.net app using salesforce credentials

Tags: integration, single-sign-on

I have an external .net mvc5 app  and we want a way to use that app from salesforce. I can create a webtab to open that application. But this would mean i would need to ask users to login into asp.net application.

Is there a way i can use the salesforce credentials to directly login into .net mvc5 app ?  I know i can make the .net app to accept the salesforce identity, i wanted to know since the salesforce user is already logged in to salesforce, can we somehow use this to login to the .net app. i really dont want to user to enter his credentials once again when he/she tries to access the .net app from salesforce

Comment: I think you have to implement your own API and handle it in .net side

Comment: The [Force.com Toolkits for .NET](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET) handles & manages login from Salesforce for .NET apps. It looks like this might work for you?

Comment: Another option would be [Force.com Canvas](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Canvas).

Comment: I was also considering Force.com Canvas.. But would require to an enterprise edition right? Can we package an canvas app?

Answer (score 1):

What about turning on [Salesforce as an Identity Provider](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=identity_provider_enable.htm&language=en_US) and standing up your .NET app as a Service Provider? Then, using SP-initiated SAML, if a user already has a session on Salesforce, should be seamlessly taken into the .NET app (ETA: when they hit the web tab with the .NET app in it).

We did this a few years ago for a client (pre-Canvas) with just basic iframe integration and the experience was seamless (minus the small but noticeable browser redirects involved in every SAML transaction).

Comment: Wouldnt we need to login into .net app even if there is a salesforce session in place while using salesforce as identity provider? Is there any documentation regarding this?

Comment: If you set up the .NET app as a service provider that speaks SAML to SFDC as an Identity provider, no, you would not need to login to the .NET app again.